# Personalizando a apresentação de post no looping do wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou querendo personalizar o looping do meus posts para exibir os posts da seguinte maneira, o primeiro para a esquerda e  o segundo para a direita e assim sucessivamente. Deu errado(e eu sabia que ia dar), mas fiz um teste da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <p align="left"><?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>
            <?php the_time( $d ); ?> 
            <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></p>

            <p align="right"><?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>
            <?php the_time( $d ); ?> 
            <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></p>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sem posts para exibição' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Isso foi só um teste para ver se dava certo, bom, não deu...
Gostaria de uma ajuda dos crânios, porque não achei o que eu queria na documentação... 
Obrigado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer coisas do tipo "uma vez isso, uma vez aquilo", você pode usar o [operador módulo](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php). Este operador funciona retornando o resto de uma divisão. De tal maneira, basta que você tenha um contador para controlar cada vez que você passa pelo *loop*, e checar o resto da divisão por 2, algo como `$resto = $contador % 2;`. O resto da divisão por 2 te diz se um numero é par ou ímpar, visto que `0` e `1` são os únicos valores possíveis para esta operação. Fazendo essa checagem (`if ($resto == 1)`) você pode realizar ações vez sim, vez não. Veja este `snippet` em JS que exemplifica melhor a situação:

```js
var count = 0;

for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
  var resto = count % 2;
  if(resto == 1){
    $('.target').append("<p>" + i + " é impar </p>");
  }
  else{ //resto == 0
    $('.target').append("<p>" + i + " é par </p>");
  }
  
  ++count;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="target"></div>
```

É possível fazer a mesma coisa no seu *loop*. De uma maneira simplificada, você pode fazer:

```
<?php

$count = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    if ($count % 2 == 1){
        $align = "left";
    } else{
        $align = "right";
    }

    ?>

    <p align="<?php echo $align?>"><?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>
        <?php the_time( $d ); ?> 
        <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?>
    </p>

    <?php ++$count; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Assim, a casa passagem do *loop*, você vai alinhar ou à esquerda, ou à direita.

Mas veja, `<p align="left">` ou `<p align="left">` vão apenas justificar o texto à direção especificada. Se você quiser fazer algo como um grid, ou cada post flutuando de um lado diferente, minha recomendação é de que use coisas como `float: left` e um certo comprimento para cada *container* do post. Mas isso, claro, é um chute. Tudo depende do que você está tentando fazer!

Comment: A respeito do css eu manjo man, vlw! Fiz desse jeito só para teste mesmo... Mas pedi uma ajuda e Recebi uma aula! Muito obrigado!